# How do i execute powershell command's with pipes in python?

Tags: powershell, python, active-directory, pipe

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('powershell.exe [Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership %USERNAME% | select name]')
os.system('powershell.exe Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership %USERNAME% | select name]')
```

I have tried bot of these with varying attempts to escape each character, exclude each character etc. I'm lost.

All I want to do is have a function in python that runs Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership, Pipes it to select then pipes it to out-file so I can store it. But if I include a pipe in the command the window will always close upon opening and no output is produced.

I can't tell what's wrong since I can't see what the PS window is doing and I don't know why it specifically has an issue with pipes.

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing Python/ cmd.exe variable names in a PowerShell.

PowerShell has no idea what %USENAME% is and will error out, as it is not a PowerShell construct.

You should absolutely see what the PowerShell.exe console is doing because you are using an external to call Powershell.exe and that is a completely separate session start than the python session you are in.

Thus you'd see not only the python console but the PowerShell console should popup as well, and if you want to see what it is doing, you need to use either the pause, -wait or noexit switches. See the PowerShell help file for more details.

PowerShell automatic variable requires you to specify the user name like this:

```
$env:USERNAME
```

not this:

```
%USERNAME%
```

PowerShell has many automatic variables that come from the Env drive.

```
Get-PSDrive | Format-Table -AutoSize
<#
# Results

Name     Used (GB) Free (GB) Provider    Root                CurrentLocation
----     --------- --------- --------    ----                ---------------
...                                
Env                          Environment                                    
...
#>

Get-ChildItem -Path 'env:\'
<#
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                       
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                       
ALLUSERSPROFILE                C:\ProgramData                                                                                                                                              
APPDATA                        C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming                                                                                                                             
CommonProgramFiles             C:\Program Files\Common Files                                                                                                                               
CommonProgramFiles(x86)        C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files                                                                                                                         
CommonProgramW6432             C:\Program Files\Common Files                                                                                                                               
COMPUTERNAME                   LP70                                                                                                                                                        
ComSpec                        C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe                                                                                                                                 
DriverData                     C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData                                                                                                                      
HOMEDRIVE                      C:                                                                                                                                                          
HOMEPATH                       \Users\Daniel                                                                                                                                               
LOCALAPPDATA                   C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local                                                                                                                               
LOGONSERVER                    \\LP70                                                                                                                                                      
MSMPI_BENCHMARKS               C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Benchmarks\                                                                                                                  
MSMPI_BIN                      C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\                                                                                                                         
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS           8                                                                                                                                                           
OneDrive                       C:\Users\Daniel\OneDrive                                                                                                                                    
OneDriveConsumer               C:\Users\Daniel\OneDrive                                                                                                                                    
OS                             Windows_NT                                                                                                                                                  
Path                           C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System...
PATHEXT                        .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL                                                                                                  
POWERSHELL_DISTRIBUTION_CHA... MSI:Windows 10 Pro                                                                                                                                          
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE         AMD64                                                                                                                                                       
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER           Intel64 Family 6 Model 94 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel                                                                                                          
PROCESSOR_LEVEL                6                                                                                                                                                           
PROCESSOR_REVISION             5e03                                                                                                                                                        
ProgramData                    C:\ProgramData                                                                                                                                              
ProgramFiles                   C:\Program Files                                                                                                                                            
ProgramFiles(x86)              C:\Program Files (x86)                                                                                                                                      
ProgramW6432                   C:\Program Files                                                                                                                                            
PSModulePath                   C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;C:\Prog...
PUBLIC                         C:\Users\Public                                                                                                                                             
PyCharm Community Edition      C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2.4\bin;                                                                                          
SystemDrive                    C:                                                                                                                                                          
SystemRoot                     C:\Windows                                                                                                                                                  
TEMP                           C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Temp                                                                                                                          
TMP                            C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Temp                                                                                                                          
USERDOMAIN                     LP70                                                                                                                                                        
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE      LP70                                                                                                                                                        
USERNAME                       Daniel                                                                                                                                                      
USERPROFILE                    C:\Users\Daniel                                                                                                                                             
windir                         C:\Windows 
#>
```

You get to each for those by their variable name:

```
$env:USERNAME
$env:USERPROFILE
$env:COMPUTERNAME
```

It may be that you are really good a Python, but why are you using Python to do PowerShell stuff, vs using PowerShell directly, especially when trying to use ADDS (RSAT) cmdlets? Unless you have Windows RSAT installed/enabled on your host

[Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7 with Service Pack 1 (SP1)](https://web.archive.org/web/20200814041744/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887)

[Install RSAT for Windows 10 1809 and 1903 and 1909 automated](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/)

[Use PowerShell Active Directory Cmdlets Without Installing Any Software](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-active-directory-cmdlets-without-installing-any-software/)

or you have made an implicit/explicit Powershell remote connection

[about_Remote - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://www.bing.com/search?q=about_remoting&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&ghc=1&pq=about_remo&sc=3-10&sk=&cvid=90DC9F18DF2640B4AF7726EDC35BFA11)

[PowerShell implicit remoting active directory](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20implicit%20remoting%20active%20directory&qs=AS&pq=powershell%20implicit%20re&sk=AS2&sc=3-22&cvid=83F27BAB90834B9096E9A6BD87581878&FORM=QBRE&sp=3)

...to a DC (or another host that has the RSAT tools), to proxy those cmdlets to you PowerShell session, then they are not even available for use.

You are not using the cmdlet syntax property as well.

[Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adprincipalgroupmembership?view=win10-ps)

This leads one to assume that you are new to ADDS with PowerShell, which is fine but should send you to get ramped up on both natively, before trying to merge with an outside language.

Bounce over to Youtube search for

- 'Beginning PowerShell',
- 'Intermediate PowerShell',
- 'Advanced PowerShell'
- and search for ['PowerShell active directory'](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%27powershell%20active%20directory%27)
- and ['PowerShell active directory Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership'](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell%20active%20directory%20Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership)

So, this is what I am illustrating in my other comments. and why if you are trying to spin this off a Python session, vs directly from PowerShell, that it can be a bit of a challenge, because of what Python needs to run and call PowerShell for Powershell to have the resources to run a given cmdlet.
I do not have Python in an environment, nor do I need it, to test this. I do PSremting every day, as do many in the industry and it works just fine.

```
# Change this...
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('powershell.exe [Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership %USERNAME% | select name]')
os.system('powershell.exe Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership %USERNAME% | select name]')

# To this, Impot the process 
import subprocess
# Use a subprocess to start powershel.exe, which creates an implicit PowerShell remote session to a DC to proxy the RSAT/ADDS cmdlets to get group information
subprocess.call(["C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", "$DCSssion = New-PSSession –ComputerName 'YourDCName'", "Invoke-Command –Session $DCsession –ScriptBlock {Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $env:USERNAME | Select-Object -Property Name}"])
```

Point of note:
To invoke commands on a remote host you must be an admin on that remote host.

***Update based on your thread ***

> I can't handle the data as nicely and it's clunky as hell but it works

PowerShell returns objects, by design/default, not strings. So, when you run stuff like this...

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $ntaccount1 |
select-Object -Property Name | 
Where-Object {$PSItem.name -like '*certain string*' } |
Sort Name
```

All you get back is one property object. Name sorted ascending. You could also do this if all you wanted was one property...

```
(Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $ntaccount1).Name |
Where-Object {$PSItem.name -like '*certain string*' } |
Sort-Object -Property Name
```

Of course, if you wanted to see all properties of a single user object...

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity '*'|
select-Object -First 1 
select-Object -Property '*'
```

If you put this in a variable, you just dot reference each property

```
$ADpgm = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity '*' |
select-Object -First 1 
select-Object -Property '*'


# See all properties and methods on an object
$ADpgm | Get-Member

# Get one property value
$ADpgm.Name


# Get specifics for a module, cmdlet, or function
(Get-Command -NameGet-ADPrincipalGroupMembership).Parameters
(Get-Command -NameGet-ADPrincipalGroupMembership).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -NameGet-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Examples
Get-help -NameGet-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Full
Get-help -NameGet-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Online
```

Comment: Sorry post was unclear

%USERNAME% Isnt literally being used. I just didn't want to insert an actual example. Should have used jon.doe instead. 

Yes, I am not familiar with PowerShell scripting to a level where I can accomplish what I needed to. 

I have tried pause/wait style commands but as soon as I include a pipe character they don't seem to trigger and I don't know why.

Comment: No worries, but unless you have to use python, you are really over complicating this. Just use PowerShell explicitly, since it is PowerShell that is really doing this work. You still cannot use any of the AD cmdlets, they are not part of a default PowerShell install as noted above. So, you have not said what OS you are using, what version of PowerShell you are targeting, and if you've installed RSAT or have remote access to a DC for them to be used. Without all the requisite PowerShell environment resources in place, you cannot do that you are trying at all with or without Python in the mix.

Comment: See my update for you to see it works out for you.

Comment: I switched over to PowerShell and got it to work easily. I can't handle the data as nicely and it's clunky as hell but it works. Ty

Comment: No worries, and good to hear, but remember PowerShell is an Object-Oriented language. So, what you'd get back is always an object that can be easily used, using object notation to extract or report on the data stream received. Also, please be sure to mark this as your accepted answer for the benefit of others who come across this post.

Comment: Can't find where to mark solved.

Comment: It should be just a checkbox on your screen, yet see these steps: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers --- What should I do when someone answers my question?
...Accept it. As the asker, you have a special privilege: you may accept the answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
...
To accept an answer: Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
...